# Apache2 mod_rewrite, handling the optional "/" at the end of a URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache-2.4, regex

I am attempting to host a single custom page to set as my homepage on my server.

The real path to the page is **example.com/start.html**.

However, I do not want this ugly URL in my homepage so I am trying to make it so that the path is **example.com/start/**.

My .htaccess file contents is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule    ^start\/?$    start.html    [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This makes **example.com/start** redirect properly, but **example.com/start/** leads to a 404 error (emphasis on the slash at the very end of the URL).  The error I get is:

```
The requested URL /start.html/ was not found on this server.
```

I believe that my regex in the RewriteRule is correct (where it should accept either "start" or "start/", so I am not sure what the problem is.

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: Splitting it into two rules might be useful for figuring out what is going on? One with the trailing slash and one without?

Also, it seems like escaping the slash is not necessary...

Comment: Hmm, even if I create two separate rules it does not seem to work.  I made one rule that searches for ^start/$ and one that searches for ^start$ and still no dice.  Only the example.com/start url redirects correctly.

Comment: I'm wondering if the one with the trailing slash gets processed at all... (My mod_rewrite knowledge is not what it should be...) There is a setting (AllowNoSlash) about trailing slashes that might be relevant, but it seems to mainly concern directories... Context for the RewriteRule also seems to affect behaviour...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/333402/apache-mod-rewrite-adding-extra-slash-at-the-end-of-url?rq=1 might also be relevant...

Comment: Why guess what's happening when you can set LogLevel rewrite:trace8?  This rule works just fine for me in isolation.